# How to add "text qualifier" in Azure data factory sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi the requirement is to add text qualifiers for output file via Azure data factory

example

"text1","text2","text3"  -----> this is header

"a","b","c","d"

Regards
Rk

Comment: Can you describle more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Quote All option in the Sink settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#sink-properties